# Regex: Always match everything, but ignore if special string are found in a specific place

Tags: regex

I have a few stripped URLs

```
en/Category/Games/TMNT/L-Michelangelo/Donatello-Groupie-Ice/p/1-23-Raphael;jsessionid=F9877C7888FFC882
en/Category/Comics/Mortal-Combat/KO/Finish-Him/p/1111111-300-Y-E-S
en/Category/Games/Dark-Knight/L-Batman/Joker-110/p/123-456-Green
en/Category/Games/Pokemon/Co-Nintendo/M-Set/p/7143499-990-Pokeball
en/Category/Games/Battlefield/c/2142
```

Normaly I use this to match them all:

```
/^en\/(.+)$/
```

Or maybe:

```
/^en\/Category\/Games\/(.+)$/
```

To only match the Games.

**This works very good!**

But now, I watch to match everything but not the urls that contain **Pokemon** or **Mortal-Combat** on the "fourth url catalogue".

Like this, tried to use *(?!Test).** make it with brakets;

```
/^en\/(.+)\/(.+)\/[(?!Pokemon).*|(?!Mortal-Combat).*]\/(.+)$/
```

But it don't work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want...

```
^en\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(?!Pokemon)(?!Mortal-Combat)([^\/]+)\/(.+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Firstly, don't capture `.+` as it captures all the way to the end of the line in most cases, but instead capture `[^\/]+` (not forward slash, 1 or more times) so it restricts the capture by the boundary you want in this case.

Secondly, the negative look-aheads don't move the cursor when they execute, so they just sit net to each other, like saying the next characters are not `Pokemon` and the next characters (still without moving cursor) are not `Mortal-Combat`.

The last capture group captures everything until the end of the string.

If you want to capture `Mortal-Combat-II` but not `Mortal-Combat` then add an escaped slash to the end of the negative lookahead, so it looks only at matches terminating with the match text...

```
(?!Pokemon\/)(?!Mortal-Combat\/)
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OaePRRrI3sVyocpz)

Comment: +1 because you did not forget the `on the fourth url catalogue` part like I did :-P

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex to get the urls except the ones that contain "Pokemon" or "Mortal-Combat":

```
(?!.*Pokemon|.*Mortal-Combat)^en\/(.+)$
```

see demo: http://regex101.com/r/fB5uD6

Note: I had overseen the *on the fourth url catalogue* condition in your question. So this regex will check if an url does not have those words *anywhere*

Answer (score 0):

This will restrict the search to only filter those lines with Pokémon or Mortal-Combat in the 4th "slot"

```
/^en\/(?!([^\/]+\/){2}(Pokemon|Mortal-Combat)\/)/
```